# Custom bootloader for Arduino

Tags: c++, assembly, arduino, bootloader

I have searched as wide as the internet is (hyperbole intended), but can't seem to find how to create a custom bootloader for Arduino.

I know how to create a bootloader for PCs/Machine; I've read enough theory and even tried to create a couple with success, but it seems almost impossible to create one for Arduino.

Opening the source - code for the Arduino bootloader (the prebuilt one) doesn't make any sense: there is no form of documentation on the compilation, etc. of the bootloader.

If, anyone, is able to provide me a start, I'll me more than grateful; thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

A boot loader for the AVR chips is just a small program that sits in the boot loader section of the FLASH. You configure the chip to boot to this location using the fuses. If you are using interrupts you also need to move the interrupt table. 
The bootloader itself will do something along the lines of read something from the serial port, decode it and program it into the flash. You usually have other supporting functions like erase flash and calculate the CRC.
A start would be obtain the data sheet for the chip and Atmel studio. www.avrfreaks.com will help you too.

Comment: Mark, the point of the question was to ask for a simple bootloader sample or any **specific** link. Your answers seems really vague and contains redundant information. I am sorry to be rude, but I am just advising you for your future answers.

Comment: @user3102854 The problem is with your question, not Mark's answer. Asking for a link to sample code is off-topic here. Mark attempted answered an on-topic version of your question. His answer is a good overview of the process and is neither vague nor redundant. It might appear that way if you don't understand some of the basic terminology that he's using.

Comment: @user3102854 You seem not to be aware that the term "boot loader" means something completely different on PCs and on Flash microcontrollers. On Flash microcontrollers it is an OPTIONAL program that allows re-placing the other content of the Flash memory over a peripheral port (such as USB). Unlike PCs that have a BIOS on (smaller) microcontrollers the program written by the user will typically be started directly by the hardware so that there is no need for an equivalent of that what is called "boot loader" on a PCs. The optional "boot loader" is just a part of that program...

Comment: Thanks a lot, people! :)

Comment: weidpanda, Having re-read my post I can see that the answer does appear to be a bit general. However if you read the data sheet for the AVR chip you want to write your bootloader for you will see I am being quite specific. The following is for the ATmega32.  http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf